# how to add text to next line in tab separated file from other file?

Tags: bash, perl, shell, csv, file-handling

I have a set of files contain tab separated values, at the last but third line, I have my desired values. I have extracted that value with

```
cat result1.tsv | tail -3 | head -1 > final1.tsv 
cat resilt2.tsv | tail -3 | head -1 >final2.tsv
```

..... so on (I have almost 30-40 files)
I want the content of final tsv files in next line in a new single file.

I tried

```
cat final1.tsv final2.tsv > final.tsv
```

but this works for the limited amount of files difficult to write the  name of all files.
I tried to put the file names in a loop as variables  but not worked.

`final1.tsv` contains:

```
270   96  284  139  271  331  915  719  591 1679 1751 1490  968 1363 1513 1184 1525  490  839  425  967  855  356
```

`final2.tsv` contains:

```
1    1    0    2    6    5    1    1   11    7    1    3    4    1    0    3    2    1    0    3    2    1   28
```

all the files (final1.tsv,final2.tsv,final3.tsv,final5..... contains same number of columns but different values)
I want the rows of each file merged in new file like

final.tsv

```
final1  270   96  284  139  271  331  915  719  591 1679 1751 1490  968 1363 1513 1184 1525  490  839  425  967  855  356
final2    1    1    0    2    6    5    1    1   11    7    1    3    4    1    0    3    2    1    0    3    2    1   28
final3  270   96  284  139  271  331  915  719  591 1679 1751 1490  968 1363 1513 1184 1525  490  839  425  967  855  356
final4    1    1    0    2    6    5    1    1   11    7    1    3    4    1    0    3    2    1    0    3    2    1   28
```

Comment: How big are `result1.tsv` etc? How many lines to they contain?

Comment: `resut1.tsv` contains approximately 1000 or more lines but at last but the third line contains the value I need. I extracted those with command 
`cat result1.tsv | tail -3 | head -1 > final1.tsv`

Answer (score 0):

here you go...

```
for f in final{1..4}.tsv; 
do 
    echo -en $f'\t' >> final.tsv; 
    cat $f >> final.tsv; 
done
```

Comment: I have more than 4 files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rm final.tsv
for FILE in result*.tsv
do
    tail -3 $FILE | head -1 >> final.tsv
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the files aren't enormous, it's simplest to read each file into an array and select the third record from the end

This solves your problem for you. It looks for all files in the current directory that match `result*.tsv` and writes the required line from each of them to `final.tsv`

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @results = sort {
    my ($aa, $bb) = map /(\d+)/, ($a, $b);
    $aa <=> $bb;
} glob 'result*.tsv';

open my $out_fh, '>', 'final.tsv';

for my $result_file ( @results ) {

    open my $fh, '<', $result_file or die qq({Unable to open "$result_file" for input: $!};
    my @data = <$fh>;

    next unless @data >= 3;

    my ($name) = $result_file =~ /([^.]+)/;
    print { $out_fh } "$name\t$data[-3]";
}
```